# Is it possible to run a gulp task from visual studio with arguments

Tags: visual-studio-2015, task-runner-explorer

I have a gulp task which accepts arguments using yargs. From the command line I do something like `gulp scaffold:thing --name=someName --path=some/path-to/{thing}`. I would like to be able to call this and prompt the user to input the needed parameters, is this possible with task runner?

I've tried using node's param library but visual studio output doesn't show the prompt at all.